# Inequality regarding Summation

Tags: inequality, summation

I need your expertise in solving the following problem:

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $b = n \cdot a$ and $d = n \cdot c$.
What is the upper bound for $y \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that the following applies:
$$ \frac{a+c}{b+d} \geq y \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} \right)$$

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{a+c}{b+d} &\ge y \cdot \left(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} \right)\\
\frac{a+c}{na+nc} & \ge y \cdot \left(\frac{a}{na} + \frac{c}{nc} \right)\\
\frac{1}{n} & \ge y \cdot \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n}\right)\\
\frac{1}{n} & \ge y \cdot \frac{2}{n} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \ge y
\end{align*}

So 1/2 is an upper bound for y.

Comment: what will happen if $b \geq a$ and not necessarily $b = n \cdot a$ ?

Answer (score 0):

plugging the conditions into the given inequality we have
$$\frac{1}{n}\geq y\cdot \frac{2}{n}$$ and now? what about $n$? and for $n>0$ we get
$$\frac{1}{2}\geq y$$

Comment: That clinches it. The equations imply that $n$ is a positive real number.